# Python Selenium: Quitting a browser instance outside of original function

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, exit

I started learning python + selenium a few days ago, and am struggling to quit the browser *outside* of my `bbdc_check` function. **My goal** is whenever I interrupt `bbdc_check` or it encounters an error, I would like to quit the existing browser to start from scratch.

I keep encountering errors with quitting the browser. The error message for `driver.quit()` is "TypeError: quit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'".

I have a nagging suspicion that I'm supposed to use a *class* here, which I tried loosely off [this solution](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1941/how-do-i-close-the-browser-window-at-the-end-of-a-selenium-test), but still could not get it to work. Any ideas are appreciated, thank you.

*FYI, `date_a` and `date_b` are not defined here because I deleted a bunch of code redundant to this issue. Assume that line of code works.*

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import sys

breakloop = 0

def bbdc_check():
    global breakloop
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\<some dir>\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get('<a website>')

    # A bunch of code here to compare 2 different dates
    if (date_a < date_b):
        breakloop = 1
    else:
        driver.quit()
        time.sleep(600)
        
# The main while-loop to run the programme
while breakloop == 0:
    try:
        bbdc_check()

    # If I manually interrupt, kill the programme
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome
        driver.quit()
        sys.exit()

    # If programme encounters error, try again from scratch
    except:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome
        driver.quit()
        time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: Why are you creating driver object again and again  ?

Comment: @ cruisepandey Right. So I've tried removing the line `driver = webdriver.Chrome` from the exceptions, but it doesn't work. How would I avoid creating multiple driver objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are creating new object of driver in each blocks as well as your function bbdc_check(). Create a single driver instance and use the same.

Comment: noted. I've tried removing the line `driver = webdriver.Chrome` from the exceptions, but it doesn't work. How do I reference the same driver instance outside of the original function?

Comment: @blimsiang, please use it in the same way as you have used breakloop...a global driver..or else you can also have driver after the function gets over and pass it as a parameter in the function...

Comment: Of course! How silly... That makes complete sense, and has fixed the code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thats great your code is fixed...Happy crawling!